How to implement textbox feature using cytoscape?
Im building a frontend project with react and cytoscape.
and I need to implement textbox feature that satisfies the following requirements
(Overally, the textbox should be look like that of PowerPoint)

user can directly edit textbox content while seeing diagram
user can edit textcolor within textbox

